# Writing a lambda expression for a really basic class

Tags: java, lambda, interface

There are two functional interfaces

```
public interface BoolBiFunction {
boolean apply( int p1, int p2 );
}


public interface IntFunction {
int apply(int p);
}
```

And the following class

```
public class IntData {
private int[] intValues;

public IntData(int[] p) {
    intValues = p;
}

public int compute(BoolBiFunction f, IntFunction g, int x) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int value : intValues) {
        if (f.apply(value, x)) {
            result = result + g.apply(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The task is use parameters so compute tells how often a number occurs within the field intValues.
But to be honest I don't really understand what the given method compute even does.

```
if ( f.apply( value, x ) )
{
result = result + g.apply( value );
 }
```

f seems to compare the two ints, but what does g.apply even do?
And how would the lambda expression for checking how often a number occurs in the field intValues?

Comment: As long as you do not show us the concrete implementations of the two given lambdas we also do not know what the lambdas do. Show us the caller of compute()

Comment: Where did you see this code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `compute` method accepts a `BoolBiFunction` that tests whether two `int` values satisfy some condition. If they satisfy the condition (i.e. if `f.apply(value, x)` is `true`), the result of applying the `IntFunction` on the current value is added to a total.

If you want, for example, to find out how many elements of the `intValues` array are equal to 5, you have to call:

```
IntData someObject = ...
int numberOf5s = someObject.compute((x,y) -> x == y,
                                    x -> 1,
                                    5);
```

This means that the `BoolBiFunction` will return `true` if and only if the two `int`s passed to it are equal.

The `IntFunction` will always return `1`, so it will count the number of times the 3rd argument - 5 - is found in the `intValues` array.

Given the above parameters passed to `compute()`, if we replace the calls to `f.apply` and `g.apply` with the actual bodies of the corresponding lambda expressions, we'll get:

```
public int compute(BoolBiFunction f, IntFunction g, int x) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int value : intValues) {
        if (value == 5) { // which is equivalent to if (f.apply(value, x)) when x == 5
            result = result + 1; // which is equivalent to result = result + g.apply(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide the concrete implementations of the two given lambdas, I'd like to explain with a simple example:

To call `compute()` method we need the implementations of `BoolBiFunction` and `IntFunction`

```
BoolBiFunction f = (p1, p2) -> p1>p2;
IntFunction g = p -> p*2;
```

Then we initialize `x` and `intValues`

```
x = 1;
intValues= {1, 3, 5};
```

Call the `compute()` method

```
int result = compute(f, g, x);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
16
```

Values at each step of the `for` loop:

```
value       x       f.apply(value,x)        g.apply(value)      result
1           1       false                   -                   0
3           1       true                    6                   0+6 = 6
5           1       true                    10                  6+10 = 16
```

In this example `g.apply(value)` returns `value*2`

Because implementation of `Intfunction` is `p -> p*2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks a bit odd to me. But, here is a solution.

Look at the code comments to understand what is happening. I have included an extra example of how you could use the same compute(...) function to find out how many times a given number occurs in that array.

```
public class Temp {
    static int [] testData = {2, 5, 11, 2, 2, 7, 6, 3, 1, 9, 10, 6};

    public static void main(String [] args){
        answerToQuestion();
        //extraQuestionForYou();
    }

    public static void answerToQuestion(){
        //How many times does 2 occur in testData ? Answer is 3. Confirm it!

        IntData intFinder = new IntData(testData);
        int desiredNumber = 2;

        int times = intFinder
                //Find out how many times desiredNumber occurs in an array.
                .compute(
                //A function which tells me if one number is equal to another.
                (number1, number2) -> number1 == number2,
                //A function which says that it saw a number one more time, every time it sees that number.
                someNumber -> 1,
                //The number whose occurrence we want to find in an array.
                desiredNumber
                );

        //Testing - Runs only when assertions are enabled for your JVM. Set VM args = -ea for your IDE.
        assert times == 3 : "Expected " + desiredNumber + " to occur 3 times, but got " + times;
    }

}
```

**What is happening inside the compute function ?**

**f.apply(value, x) :**

```
f = (number1, number2) -> number1 == number2.
f.apply(value, x) means number1 = value and number2 = x.
```

**result = result + g.apply(value) :**

```
g = someNumber -> 1.
g.apply(value) means return 1 whenever you see value.
```

We can reuse the compute() method for doing other things like finding how many times the triple of a given number occurs in an array, besides what the original question asked. There are two ways of doing it - use the above code and search for 6, OR use a bi function which checks if one number is triple of another. We use the latter approach in the code below. You can come up with a better example instead if you'd like.

```
public static void extraQuestionForYou(){
    //How many times does triple of 2 occur in testData ? Answer is 2. Confirm it!

    IntData intFinder = new IntData(testData);
    int desiredNumber = 2;

    int times = intFinder
            //Find out how many times triple of desiredNumber occurs in an array.
            .compute(
                    //A function which tells me if one number is equal to triple of another.
                    (number1, number2) -> number1 * 3 == number2,
                    //A function which says that it saw a number one more time, every time it sees that number.
                    someNumber -> 1,
                    //The number whose "triples" we want to find in an array.
                    desiredNumber
            );

    //Testing - Runs only when assertions are enabled for your JVM. Set VM args = -ea for your IDE.
    assert times == 2 : "Expected " + desiredNumber + " to occur 2 times, but got " + times;
}
```